# Transformar uma consulta de várias linhas em Apenas Uma Linha com todos os registros no MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Alguém com conhecimento em MYSQL para me ajudar neste caso?

Como transformar uma consulta que gera várias linhas em apenas uma linha com todos os registros um ao lado do outro no banco MySql.

Exemplo na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: So tem um problema, o MySQL suporte somente 4066 colunas. Poderia explicar o motivo  de estar querendo fazer isso?

Comment: Não chegará nem a 50 colunas. A finalidade é que todos esses registros fiquem na mesma linha para inserir dentro de um array no php e posteriormente inserir numa planilha do excel que a aplicação irá gerar. Vou substituir cada id por: 
Primeira Fila,
Segunda Fila,
Terceira Fila, 
Quarta Fila.

Comment: Eu acho que não da pra fazer isso que esta querendo, mesmo que der acredito que não seria uma boa solução. Pense em como resolver isso com o PHP e não com o MySql. Creio que será o melhor caminho.

Comment: isso chama-se *Pivot Table*, aqui no SO  uma pergunta com bons exemplos de código: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9788875/6754506)